# How do I pass a dynamic number of arguments to a batch file and how to send an argument as a string that might consists of a few words?

Tags: batch-file

I have two questions:

1) How do I pass a dynamic number of arguments to a batch file?
Assume that I have a batch file c:\test.bat. 
The batch file itself consists of `c:\test.exe %1 %2`

Now if I run "c:\test.bat aa bb" the result would be that "c:\test.exe aa bb"

I need to be able to add an unknown/dynamic amount of arguments, for example:

`c:\test.bat aa bb cc dd 33 gg`

```
c:\test.bat kk
```

2) How do I add to the above example the option to pass one argument that could consist of a few different strings, for example:

```
c:\test.bat kk "aa bb cc" dd
```

where  "aa bb cc" is one argument

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to both questions is:

```
C:\test.exe %*
```

The `%*` passes *all* arguments from the batch to the exe, and it also leaves quoted multi-word arguments intact.

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
@echo off
rem if the first parameter isn't blank, echo it
if not %1x==x echo %1
if not %2x==x echo %2
if not %3x==x echo %3
```

On the other hand, if you just pass all of the parameters to the EXE, it will only see the ones you typed at the command line and won't be upset by any you didn't type, wouldn't it?

And as to your second question, you've already answered it.  Any parameters bounded by quotes will be passed as a single parameter.